# Importrange usage to maintain subset of master data from Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a main spreadsheet where I'm keeping the full set of my data.

- Each row represents a patient's case
- There is a column that has a region (NR, SR, NZ) each case has been assigned to

I would like each regional manager (eg NZ) to have their own spreadsheet (workbook)  that:

- Dynamically selects which rows in the master match that region (NZ) in the region column
- Update the (NZ) regional spreadsheet with the rows that correspond to cases assigned to their region.

So far I understand that best function for this task is probably the `importrange` function:

```
=importrange(spreadsheet_key, range_string)
```

**Question is** how to dynamically generate the `range_string` - an updating range that targets all rows that match the region of interest?

Furthermore - do they have to be in the same workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of `QUERY` and `IMPORTRANGE`. So for example in the "NZ" sheet in A2, you could do `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Main Spreadsheet URL","Sheet Name!Range"),"Select Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1<>'' and Col4='NZ' order by Col3 asc",0)`

That would pull all rows from columns 1 (A), 3 (C) and 4 (D) into your new spreadsheet as long as a row in column 1 (A) is not empty (`Col1<>''`) and then a row in column 4 (D) is equal to "NZ" (`Col4=NZ`) and then sorts in ascending order data in column 3 (C) (`order by Col3 asc`).

You can also replace the "NZ" in the formula with a cell reference like the example below.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Main Spreadsheet URL","Sheet Name!Range"),"Select Col1, Col3, Col4 where Col1<>'' and Col4='"&Sheet2!F1&"' order by Col3 asc",0)`

Comment: Thanks will try this, btw what is the meaning of Col1<>?

Comment: That means that the first column of data is not equal to empty. So it only returns rows where the first column of data contains something. That prevents from returning empty rows. It's a little thing, but I find makes the imported data easier to manage.